# How would a registration of the .onion gtld impact the Tor network?

Tags: onion-services, anonymity, security, dns

The title pretty much says it all.

What effects would a gtld registration of .onion domain have on the Tor network, is this something to worry about? Or is it something to welcome and slap a web2tor proxy under its entire namespace?

Is it going to impact the security by the percieved notion to the general public that using a regular browser to visit `someobscurehash.onion` provides you with anonymity and protection? Or that the website you're hosting under your freshly registered domain name (or hash -- are we really silly enough to register a domain name like that) is safe from evil governments and corporations (provided whoever registers this tld would allow registration of its subdomain)?

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: You can make a post Community Wiki (CW) after you earn a certain amount of reputation. A check box will appear by the ask question button. I removed the statement about it because it's generally a good idea to ask one question per post. If you need more help, feel free to ask on [meta](http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sam, Ahh, I assumed it was `create wiki posts` @ 10 rep, however there was no checkbox to be found during post creation. You're right though, meta would be the place to ask next time, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, CW is only for answers. So when you check the "Answer your own question" check box and the answer dialog pops up, you'll then see the CW check box near the submit button. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Related to http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/446/register-onion-as-gtld.

Comment: Related, but a completely different question alltogether. That question in particular about whether or not the tor project is going to register and if it has claim. Not about the effects a registration might (will) have in general, good or bad, which is far more interesting.

Comment: related:http://superuser.com/q/652885/258600

Comment: lol, have you seen the hidden services' addresses? `lakshpoi23h5p13ou9a.onion` probably isn't going to be taken by a mainstream site...

Answer (score 4):

*(not a full answer, but relevant)*

ICANN published the study [*Name Collision in the DNS* (PDF, 3.3 MB)](http://www.icann.org/en/about/staff/security/ssr/name-collision-02aug13-en.pdf):

> A study of the likelihood and potential consequences of collision between new public gTLD labels and existing private uses of the same strings

Comment: // , How would this affect a .onion gtld, though?

Comment: // , Would we need to start using .garlic instead? <.<